# What are the SOTA Visual Representation Learning architectures for binary images?

Tags: computer-vision, transfer-learning, semi-supervised-learning, self-supervised-learning

I want to learn the visual representation of binary images such as:

[image] [image]

This may later be used for the shape classification problem. I have read 2 state-of-the-art visual representation learning architectures: [MoCo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.05722) and [SimCLR](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.05709.pdf). But they emphasize the importance of color distortion for data augmentation, which means RGB images are preferred.

So does it make sense for me to use MoCo or SimCLR to learn the visual representation of binary images? If it does not, what are the state-of-the-art architectures for solving this problem? I have searched everywhere but no specific answers could be found.

Comment: Are you planning to start training the model from scratch? Or can you use their pretrained models? Did you try to work with ResNet (or an alternative). You could just convert your binary image into a 3D tensor and it should work.

Comment: Hi @Janosch,  if I can use the pretrained models, then it will be great. But I am not quite sure how to handle the binary images as MoCo and SimCLR seem to be designed for RGB images.

Comment: Yes but black (rgb(0,0,0)) and white also exist in RGB Images. I agree that it might not be the perfect model, but I think its worth giving it a shot

Comment: Thank you, I would give it a shot.